# PIC10F200 Breakout Board - Use ICSPDAT and ICSPCLK as GPIOs?

Tags: pic, circuit-analysis, pickit

i am desinging a breakout board for the PIC10F200 at the moment and i am wondering if i am able to use ICSPDAT (GP0), ICSPCLK (GP1) and MCLR (GP3) as GPIOs if i use in-circuit debugging / programming with the PicKit3?
This is how my circuit looks like at the moment:

[image]

If i won't be able to use them i am left with only 1 GPIO, which isn't very much, 4 would be much better (or at least 3) :)

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use them as GPIOs. There are a few caveats though:

1. What you connect to the CLK and DAT pins in the way of other devices could interfere with the programming. You should include some way to isolate those devices if needed.
2. If you disable the MCLR functionality you can only use HVP mode for programming (not sure off hand if that chip does LVP or not). The >10V pulse on MCLR to enter programming mode could fry whatever is connected to it. Again you should provide some method to isolate that pin or otherwise mitigate that pulse (without interfering with the programming).

Comment: Do i need any kind of resistors for CLK and DAT to work as GPIOs or can i leave them as is? I don't find anything about high voltage programming in the datasheet, but i also don't find anything about low voltage programming :(

Comment: No, you don't need to add anything to make CLK and DAT work as GPIO. They are only CLK and DAT when in programming mode.

Comment: Only HVP mode is supported on these chips. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41228D.pdf

Comment: One more question, the PicKit3 manual recommends a 10k pullup from Vpp (12V@HVP) to Vdd (5V@normal operation). Both (vdd and vpp) are connected to PicKit3. Do you think the 12V burst will harm any circutry connected to 5V (such as temperature sensors / displays)?

Comment: No, that should be fine. 7V will be dropped across the 10KΩ resistor with 7µA flowing through it.

Comment: @Majenko ITYM 0.7mA (700uA).

Comment: That's what I meant, yes.